# LIMIT clause breaking Sequelize query with multiple eager-loaded associations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to query a model with two associations (one BelongsTo and another BelongToMany).

```
    const rows = await models.client.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'updated_at'],
        distinct: true,
        include: [
            {
                association: 'user',
                attributes: ['name', 'email']
            },
            {
                association: 'companies',
                attributes: ['name', 'ein']
            }
        ],
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { '$user.name$':      { [Op.iLike]: '%' + req.query.search + '%' } },
                { '$user.email$':     { [Op.iLike]: '%' + req.query.search + '%' } },
                { '$companies.name$': { [Op.iLike]: '%' + req.query.search + '%' } },
                { '$companies.ein$':  { [Op.iLike]: '%' + req.query.search + '%' } }
            ]
        },
        limit: 10
    });
```

The code above crashes Sequelize. But if I remove the `limit: 10` parameter, it works just fine. Specifying the limit works if I just remove the `companies` association. It also works with both the limit *and* association, but I have to remove ALL the WHERE clauses.

The association is defined in my `client` model like this:

```
        client.belongsToMany(models.company, {
            through: models.clientCompany,
            foreignKey: 'client_id',
            otherKey: 'company_id',
            as: 'companies'
        });
```

Sequelize seems to be placing the LIMIT inside a subquery and not at the top-level query, but I have no idea what's causing it to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.